# Mongodb/mongoose query for completely overlapping dates (that could span multiple documents)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, database-design

I'm having some issues designing a query that deals with overlapping dates.

So here's the scenario, I can't reveal too much about the actual project but here is a similar example. Lets say I have a `FleaMarket`. It has a bunch of data about itself such as `name`, `location`, etc.

So a `FleaMarket` would have many `Stalls`, that are available to be booked for a portion of the year (as short as 2 days, as long as all year sort of thing). So the `FleaMarket` needs to specify when in a year it will be open. Most scenarios would either be open all year, or all summer/fall, but it could possible be broken down further (because seasons determine pricing). Each `FleaMarket` would define their `Seasons` which would include a `startDate` and `endDate` (including year).

Here's an ERD to model this example:

[image]

When a user attempts to book a `Stall`, they have already selected a `FleaMarket` (although ideally it would be nice to search based on availability in the future). It's really easy to tell if a `Stall` is already booked for the requested dates:

```
bookings = await Booking.find({
  startDate: { $lt: <requested end date> },
  endDate: { $gt: <requested start date> },
  fleaMarketId: <flea market id>,
}).select('stallId');
bookedIds = bookings.map(b => b.stallId);

stalls = await Stall.find({
  fleaMarketId: <flea marked id>,
  _id: { $nin: bookedIds }
});
```

The issue I'm having is determining if a `Stall` is available for the specified `Season`. The problem comes that 2 seasons could be sequential, so you could make a booking that spans 2 seasons.

I originally tried a query like so:

```
seasons = await Season.find({
  fleaMarketId: <flea market id>,
  startDate: { $lt: <requested end date> },
  endDate: {$gt: <requested start date> }
});
```

And then programatically checked if any returned seasons were sequential, and plucked the available stalls from that that existed in all seasons. But unfortunately I just realized this won't work if the requested date only partially overlaps with a season (ex: requested `Jan 1 2020 - Jan 10 2020`, but the season is defined as `Jan 2 2020 - May 1 2020`)

Is there a way I can handle checking for completely overlapping dates that could possible overlap with multiple documents? I was thinking about calculating and storing the current and future available season dates (stored as total ranges) denormalized on the `Stall`.

At this point I'm almost thinking I need to restructure the schema quite a bit. Any recommendations? I know this seems very relational, but pretty much everywhere else in the application doesn't really do much with the relationships. It's just this search that is quite problematic.

**Update**:

I just had the thought of maybe creating some sort of `Calendar` Document that can store a centralized list of availability for a `FleaMarket`, that would do a rolling update to only store future and present data, and slowly wiping away historical data, or maybe archiving it in a different format. Perhaps this will solve my issue, I will be discussing it with my team soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as I said in an update in my post, I came up with the idea to create a rolling calendar.

For anyone who is interested, here's what I got:

I created an `Availability` collection, that contains documents like the following:

```
{
  marketId: ObjectId('5dd705c0eeeaf900450e7009'),
  stallId: ObjectId('5dde9fc3bf30e500280f80ce'),
  availableDates: [
    {
      date: '2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z',
      price: 30.0,
      seasonId: '5dd708e7534f3700a9cad0e7',
    },
    {
      date: '2020-01-02T00:00:00.000Z',
      price: 30.0,
      seasonId: '5dd708e7534f3700a9cad0e7',
    },
    {
      date: '2020-01-03T00:00:00.000Z',
      price: 35.0,
      seasonId: '5dd708e7534f3700a9cad0e8',
    }
  ],
  bookedDuring: [
    '2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z'
    '2020-01-02T00:00:00.000Z'
  ]
}
```

Then handling updates to this collection:

**Seasons**

- when creating, $push new dates onto each stall (and delete dates from the past)
- When updating, remove the old dates, and add on the new ones (or calculate difference, either works depending on the integrity of this data)
- When deleting, remove dates

**Stalls**

- When creating, insert records for associated seasons
- When deleting, delete records from availability collection

**Bookings**

- When creating, add dates to `bookedDuring`
- When updating, add or remove dates from `bookedDuring`

Then to find available stalls for a market, you can query where `{ marketId: /* market's ID */, availableDates.date: { $all: [/* each desired day */], bookedDuring: { $nin: [/* same dates */ ] } }}` and then pluck out the `stallId`

And to find markets that have available, do `{ availableDates.dates: { $all: [/* each desired day */], bookedDuring: { $nin: [/* same dates */ ] } }}` select distinct `marketIds`